# Different style for each heading rank

Tags: css, html

HTML5's new outlining structure causes user agents to render headings using the same tag at different sizes as you descend through sections. Is there a way to control this, preferably through a CSS selector?

I like to use the "h1 for everything" approach, since I can move sections in and out of the outline without re-tagging the headings, but I can't think of a way to control exactly what styles the user agent uses for each level.

Ideally I would be able to say something like `h1:level1{ font-size: 18pt }`, which would only change the section headings and `h1:level2` to select the sub-section headings. Granted, I could just as easily use `section h1` and `section section h1`, but I'm wondering if there is something cleaner than repeating "section" for as deep as my outline goes.

Comment: "H1" for everything is an SEO failure.

Comment: The h1 element is said to have the highest rank, the h6 element has the lowest rank, and **two elements with the same name have equal rank**.

Comment: @Diodeus "H1 for everything" has nothing to do with SEO.  It's about not having to worry about your headlines having the incorrect hierarchy for outline purposes when you're dealing with things like includes or syndicated content.  (see:  http://www.iheni.com/html-5-to-the-h1-debate-rescue/ and http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201106/on_using_h1_for_all_heading_levels_in_html5/)

Comment: @sachleen - ...not if they're nested within different `section`s. In HTML5, each `section` has its own rank.

Comment: @sachleen Thanks, I misunderstood the spec to mean the rank descended with sectioning blocks, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your font size in `em`s, then set your `section`'s font-size to be anything under `1em`.

For example:

```
section {
    font-size: .9em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLhFc/

Comment: That's a pretty messy way to do it since it also effects the size of the section element as well.

Comment: @cimmanon - Presumably, nested `section`s *should* actually have different styling than their parents. If that's not the case here, then I don't think `section` is what should be used in the first place...

Comment: Yes, they *should* have different styling, but you're forcing it to be font-size here.

Comment: @cimmanon - We can round and round on this, so we'll just leave it at that. You could always increase the paragraph styles back to (almost) where they were: `section p { font-size: 1.1em }`

Comment: @cimmanon - Let alone the fact that this will only affect font sizes specified in `em`s. Since the OP isn't using those anywhere else, they've got nothing to worry about.

Comment: You don't know that.  You only know the sizes of the elements the OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

The rank is part of the tag name. There is no concept of rank independent of the number in the tag. Two `<h1>` tags have equal rank regardless of where they are in the document.

> These elements have a rank given **by the number in their name**.
>   - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank

If you want to use h1 for everything and style differently depending on how far nested the element is within the structure then the best you could do is style them differently depending on the parent element(s).

For example:

```
<section class"rank1">
   <h1>Heading of Rank 1</h1>
</section>

<section class"rank2">
   <h1>Heading of Rank 2</h1>
</section>
```

And using CSS as such:

```
.rank1 h1 {
// make it big
}

.rank2 h1 {
// make it smaller
}
```

Comment: I don't agree. Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document

Comment: That article seems to be saying that ranks reset within sections. So, you can use an h1 again in a section inside another section. The fact remains that the only only way to differentiate them with CSS is to target them based on their parent elements.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way?

```
h1 { font-size: 2em }

section h1 { font-size: 1.8em }

section section h1 { font-size: 1.6em }

section section section h1 { font-size: 1.4em }
```

If you need this to work with article as well (or any combination of section+article), then you'll need to add those combinations as well (which can make for a *very* long selector).

You can save yourself a lot of retyping if you're open to a CSS preprocessor.  This particular mixin will cover cases of additional headline ranks, not just h1.

Sass + Compass:

```
$gh-selectors: 'section, article' !default;
@mixin graduated-headlines($hn: 1, $sizes: 2em 1.8em 1.4em 1.2em 1em .8em) {
    $sel: $gh-selectors;
    @for $i from 1 through length($sizes) {
        #{$sel} {
            @for $j from 1 through $hn {
                @if $i + $j - 1 <= length($sizes) {
                    h#{$j} {
                        font-size: nth($sizes, $i + $j - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $sel: nest($sel, $gh-selectors);
    }
}
```